# DateTime.Now convert to SQLDatetime using Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm using a Entity data model connected to my SQLDatabase.

One specific column is datetime.

When I declare the value as Datetime.Now I get the following error:

> **Inner Exception:** SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Here is my code snippet:

```
ReworkEntities dbContext = new ReworkEntities();

        Carton carton = new Carton();

        Carton_Details detail1 = new Carton_Details();
        detail1.Detail = "Some Detail Here";
        detail1.DateOfSub = DateTime.Now;

        carton.Carton_Details.Add(detail1);

        dbContext.AddToCartons(carton);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I spent hour on Google and found allot of similar problems but none seem to work for me.

They suggested to use .toSting("M/dd/yyyy H:mmss tt"), I works for the string value but I need the DateTime value and when converting it back it is still the same.

Also tried .Parse , .ParseExact and also no success.

Another post suggests changing the SQL Database datetime format but I cant do that as it is our code-standard to use it like that.

Any suggestions on how to fix the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx.

Comment: Are you sure that you only one fields with `DataType` is `DateTime` from this table `Carton_Detail`?

Comment: What is a `Type` of `detail1.DateofSub` property?

Comment: The property Type is DateTime, Yes the other fields post fine but only detail1.DateofSub doesnt post.

Comment: How about type of the field on SQL Server?

Comment: On sql server it is datetime and format "yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss"

Comment: This only happens if you do something like DateTime.Min. I have used DateTime.Now many times, just as you are here, with no issues. Your problem is something else. Verify what the date is and make sure it is actually the current time. Then check the DateTime type on your model and see if it is SqlDateTime or SqlDateTime2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem, just put in the constructor of your entity a value for the attribute, the code follows.

```
public class Carton_Details
{
    public DateTime DateOfSub { get; set; }

    public Carton_Details()
    {
        this.DateOfSub = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I hope I helped.